# Multiple result set in Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework

Does EF7 natively support multiple result sets? In earlier EF versions, we use Translate feature in objectContext to interpret multiple result sets but i read somewhere that objectContext was removed in EF7. What is the work around in EF7?

Answer (score 0):

In EF7 RC1, result-set mapping is built in

[Check here for the fix details](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1864)

And you can call it like this - `var userType = dbContext.Set().FromSql("dbo.SomeSproc @Id = {0}, @Name = {1}", 45, "Ada");`

Comment: I've checked the solution you mentioned here, but I cant use Set() function, it needs a generic type which is in type of TEntity, Set<T>(). I wonder if you are using special assembly reference.